# Combining calendar and chart on the same timeline, single SVG vs HTML+JavaScript Chart Library

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg

I'm trying to combine a calendar with a chart on one webpage. They need to be on the same timeline (for example to mark the current day with a line). They do not show the same data (So the calendar events are independant from the chart values).

[Illustration of how it should look (The final solution would have different views, per week, per month, per year)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WANjS.png)

My first instinct was to use a HTML table (or `<div>`s formatted like a table) in combination with a chart library, the only difficulty there is getting both variants onto the same timeline (They need to line up perfectly).

That's why the idea of using SVG came up (which seems to be the prominent idea in the team), but drawing every table cell with `<rect>`, taking into account position, border width and then also manually positioning texts (and also clipping them if they get too long) seems like a major drawback.

Is there any sane and straightforward way to implement this? I either have to use a third party chart library and try to perfectly line it up, or I draw everything into one SVG, but then everything down to the position of each text element needs to be calculated. I'm afraid if we go the SVG way every little change to the design could suddenly need hours of work (Besides supporting different chart types, combining line and bar charts, possible animations and so on).

Comment: I think it is a nice project, but I find it unlikely that someone can give you a detailed answer (if someone does, congrats!). Usually, you need to provide an example for tinkering. My two cents: you might set the calendar as a `foreignObject` inside the svg, with known dimensions and your table inside, occupying the whole width. You might then interpolate the coordinates of each border.

Comment: This seems to be a project most suited for the [tag:d3.js] library. It can draw both your graph and the tabular data in any format you choose, while taking care of most of the time scale and axis dimensioning problems. Admittedly it's going to be a bit of a learning curve if you have no prior experience with this library.

Comment: @vqf I thought about that too and it might actually be a solution to this problem. Right now I went the more hacky way and simply lined up HTML elements with a chart library (Biggest problem is that the chart content can't be fixated.. so I have to do the lining up manually). Not the best solution, but the quickest and I don't have to create my own charts.

Comment: @ccprog Looks like a pretty powerful library, but with the learning curve involved I'll probably not have enough time to use it. Right now I just created a table with divs, used FusionCharts below and lined the table up with margins (Which is hacky as the margins depend on chart content.. but better than building a SVG table).